# Spring Boot. Path for automatic scripts running at the start

Tags: database, spring-boot

For automatic scripts running at the start I use following property:

```
spring.datasource.data=classpath:base.scripts/*
```

It runs all the scripts in src/main/resources/base.scripts
But imagine my scripts files are located not in resources. (In another project directory, for example src/test/resources/base/scripts). How can I specify that path?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it:

```
spring.datasource.data=file:src/main/resources/base.scripts/*
```